# remove products from the cart using laravel in e-commerce project

Tags: php, html, laravel, e-commerce, project

this is the code of my **ProductController.php**

```
function removeCart($id)
    {
        Cart::destroy($id);
        return redirect('cartlist');
    }
```

this is my **route in web.php**

```
Route::get("removecart/{id}",[ProductController::class,'removeCart'])->name('remove');
```

this is my **balde file** code

```
<a href="{{url('/removecart/{$item->cart_id}')}}" class="btn btn-warning" >Remove from Cart</a>
```

my remove from cart button is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{url('/removecart/' . $item->cart_id)}}" class="btn btn-warning" >Remove from Cart</a>

// Or ( Recommended )

<a href="{{route('remove', $item->cart_id)}}" class="btn btn-warning" >Remove from Cart</a>
```

Comment: thank you so much Mr.Arun. your comment  is very usefull to me. first one is worked fine. again thank you

Answer (score 0):

> In Controller

```
function removeCart(Cart $id)
{
    $id->delete();
    return redirect('cartlist');
}
```

> web.php

```
Route::get("removecart/{id}",[ProductController::class,'removeCart'])->name('cart.remove');
```

In blade

```
<a href="{{route('cart.remove',$item->cart_id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">
  <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

*Use an icon that looks simple and good(Font Awesome)*
Maybe this helps you.